# Creating table with different columns

Tags: tables

I would like to produce this table in LaTeX. How can I do this ?

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not a question of automatic generation of such a table, the solution may be as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*6c}
A&B&C&D&F&G\\
\hline
&&&&&\\[-1mm] %additional space
 &x1b&x1c&x1d&x1f&x1g\\
x&x2b&x2c&x2d&x2f&x2g\\
 &x3b&x3c&x3d&x3f&x3g\\[3mm]
 &xx1b&xx1c&xx1d&xx1f&xx1g\\
xx&xx2b&xx2c&xx2d&xx2f&xx2g\\
 &xx3b&xx3c&xx3d&xx3f&xx3g\\[3mm]
 &xxx1b&xxx1c&xxx1d&xxx1f&xxx1g\\
xxx&xxx2b&xxx2c&xxx2d&xxx2f&xxx2g\\
 &xxx3b&xxx3c&xxx3d&xxx3f&xxx3g
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]